# "The parameter was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities query expression." Specification Pattern And

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-expressions

I follow the specification pattern implementation described [here](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/specification-pattern-c-implementation/). I have a repository method looking like this:

```cs
public IEnumerable<MyDto> Find(Specification<Dto> specification)
{
    return myDbContext.MyDtos.Where(specification.ToExpression()).Take(20).ToList();
}
```

If I use a normal, non-composite specification it works just fine, but the following scenario fails with message "The parameter 'r' was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities query expression.":

```cs
Specification<MyDto> spec = new Spec1(someCriterion)
    .And(new Spec2(someCriterion))
    .And(new Spec3(someCriterion))
    // etc...

var myDtos = repo.Find(spec);
```

From what I could read so far it has something to do with the parameter reference not being the same for all expressions, but I am not really sure how to fix this issue.

For reference, this is how the `AndSpecification<T>` class looks like in my code:

```cs
public class AndSpecification<T> : Specification<T>
{
    private readonly Specification<T> _left;
    private readonly Specification<T> _right;

    public AndSpecification(Specification<T> left, Specification<T> right)
    {
        _left = left;
        _right = right;
    }

    public override Expression<Func<T, bool>> ToExpression()
    {
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> leftExpression = _left.ToExpression();
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> rightExpression = _right.ToExpression();

        BinaryExpression andExpression = Expression.AndAlso(
            leftExpression.Body, rightExpression.Body);

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
            andExpression, leftExpression.Parameters.Single());
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the exception?  Have you shown us that line of code?

Comment: It might be helpful if you include the portion of code that contains the line that is throwing, along with the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: What are the parameters it's using? And what is the entity properties?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Please check the accepted answer for the solution. The parameter that the expressions for each specification are using is the DTO itself. The issue was that the parameters across expressions were not the same, despite having the same name. The solution is to make sure that the parameter of the expression at the left extremity is used across all chained expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your `ToExpression` method.

`leftExpression` and `rightExpression` are each a `LambdaExpression`, and each have their own, distinct `T` parameter.

When you create the LambdaExpression you return from `ToExpression`, you say that this should use the parameter from `leftExpression`. But what about the parameter that's used in `rightExpression`? `rightExpression.Body` contains expressions which use `rightExpression.Parameters[0]`, and they'll still continue to reference the object `rightExpression.Parameters[0]` even after you take `rightExpression.Body` and put it in another expression.

You need to rewrite `rightExpression` to use the same parameter as `leftExpression`. The easiest way to do this is using an `ExpressionVisitor`.

First, create an [`ExpressionVisitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor?view=netframework-4.8) which simply replaces one parameter with another:

```
public class ParameterReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly ParameterExpression target;
    private readonly ParameterExpression replacement;

    public ParameterReplaceVisitor(ParameterExpression target, ParameterExpression replacement) =>
        (this.target, this.replacement) = (target, replacement);

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node) =>
        node == target ? replacement : base.VisitParameter(node);
}
```

Then use this to rewrite your `rightExpression.Body`, so it uses the same parameter object as `leftExpression`:

```
var visitor = new ParameterReplaceVisitor(rightExpression.Parameters[0], leftExpression.Parameters[0]);
var rewrittenRightBody = visitor.Visit(rightExpression.Body.Visit);
var andExpression = Expression.AndAlso(leftExpression.Body, rewrittenRightBody);

return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
    andExpression, leftExpression.Parameters[0]);
```

Comment: One thing, shouldn't it be `visitor.Visit(rightExpression.Body)`?